# Computational applications of construction grammars

Tags: computational-linguistics, construction-grammar

Are there NLP applications (either natural language understanding or generation) which make use of the Construction Grammar framework?  On a related note, does there exist a logically organized list of constructions in English which could be applied to an NLG task, or a method of obtaining such a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not at all up-to-date on theory-driven NLP, but…

---

First, "Construction Grammar" (CxG) isn't a framework; it's a family of distinct (sometimes *very* distinct) frameworks or approaches that share the same core idea.

Even sticking to the ones that are most theoretically aligned (usage-based, unification-driven, etc.), you can't take a set of constructions from Adele Goldberg in her CxG and mix and match with a set of constructions from Charles Fillmore in Berkeley Construction Grammar (BCG), without doing a lot of careful work to translate.<sup>1</sup>

---

There's also some question about which frameworks are "really" CxG, and some of the most useful work is in those borderline frameworks.

The most obvious example is Head-driven Phrase Structure Grammar (HPSG). While HPSG was originally designed by people outside the CxG universe, and described as a unification-driven bottom-up generative PSG, not a CxG—but it turns out to be very CxG-like in practice. In fact, it's easier to translate data between Berkeley Construction Grammar (BCG) and HPSG than between BCG and some other CxGs. So, is HPSG really a CxG after all? Or a hybrid?

If you don't care about the answer to that question, then there's a ton of NLP work driven by HPSG—projects like [DELPH-IN](http://www.delph-in.net/) and [CoreGram](https://hpsg.hu-berlin.de/Projects/CoreGram.html)/[Babel](https://hpsg.hu-berlin.de/~stefan/Babel/Interaktiv/), and the theoretical and data-collection work behind them—which could be directly useful to you.

But if it matters to you (and you don't believe that HPSG qualifies as a CxG), then you can't use any of that work. Some of it has translations to or successors in Sign-Based Construction Grammar, which is definitely a CxG, and can be seen as sort of a merger of BCG and HPSG, but definitely not all of it.

---

<sub>1. Correlating two CxG frameworks *informally* is usually pretty simple—Goldberg can write a paper with Ray Jackendoff that fits into both of their frameworks, with only a few footnotes to explain where the rough edges are. But doing so *formally* is not so easy.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on this, but plan on writing my dissertation on something similar. Since no one has answered yet, here are a couple of resources:

- https://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~miriamp/fillmore-tribute/slides/Collin_Baker.pdf - This talks about some NLP applications of FrameNet, which is based on CG
- https://www.fcg-net.org/ - Fluid CG, which is an instantiation of CG.

I'd love to hear about more, though.

Comment: have you looked at https://github.com/swabhs/open-sesame for an automatic parser into framenet frames?